# Friend request that now shows "cancel"

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

If I sent a friend request to someone and now in that box it says *cancel*, does that mean that person cancelled my request?

Answer (score 3):

No, it means that the person has a friend request in their account and they have not yet accepted it.  If you click on "Cancel", then that will remove the friend request from their account, and Facebook would give you the option to send another friend request.

Answer (score -1):

If the user has reject the friend request send by you ,When you visit the friend page you get the option as Add Friend so Friend hasn't rejected your request and he hasn't decide yet to add you.